# Removal of auth info fails due to bad implicit parameter

Tags: scala, playframework, silhouette

I'm using Silhouette to manage authentication in my Play application. Registration, login and authorization work fine. However, when trying to unregister (= delete) a user account, deletion of the corresponding auth info fails.

In particular, the following line throws an exception:

```scala
authInfoRepository.remove(LoginInfo(credentialsProvider.id, username))
```

(`authInfoRepository` is an injected `AuthInfoRepository`, which is configured to be a `DelegableAuthInfoRepository`)

*Exception:*

```
com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Cannot remove auth info of type: class scala.runtime.Nothing$; Please configure the DAO for this type
at com.mohiva.play.silhouette.persistence.repositories.DelegableAuthInfoRepository.remove(DelegableAuthInfoRepository.scala:115)
[...]
```

Looking at the method in question, it expects an implicit parameter `implicit tag: ClassTag[T]`. That one somehow ends up being `Nothing`, which looks wrong in my eyes, but I don't fully understand what's going on, or what is expected to happen.

- How should `AuthInfoRepository#remove` be properly called? Do I need to manually put a `ClassTag` object into the right context to avoid `Nothing` to be inferred?
- Why is the implicit `ClassTag` parameter even relevant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is the implicit `ClassTag` parameter even relevant?

`ClassTag` is relevant because `remove` expects such implicit: https://github.com/mohiva/play-silhouette/blob/master/silhouette-persistence/src/main/scala/com/mohiva/play/silhouette/persistence/repositories/DelegableAuthInfoRepository.scala#L104-L118

> Do I need to manually put a `ClassTag` object into the right context to
>   avoid `Nothing` to be inferred?

I guess vice versa, you should specify `T` (without such specifying, `T` is now inferred to be `Nothing`) and proper implicit will be found.

Try one of options:

```
authInfoRepository.remove[CasInfo](LoginInfo(credentialsProvider.id, username))
authInfoRepository.remove[OAuth1Info](LoginInfo(credentialsProvider.id, username))
authInfoRepository.remove[OAuth2Info](LoginInfo(credentialsProvider.id, username))
authInfoRepository.remove[OpenIDInfo](LoginInfo(credentialsProvider.id, username))
authInfoRepository.remove[PasswordInfo](LoginInfo(credentialsProvider.id, username))
```

Comment: Ah, now I see: The type is necessary because of different supported methods of authentication. Thanks!